# Game Center game development time limit?

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center

Apparently I have to create my App on iTunes Connect in order to use Game Center code in my project. But wait, I remember that if you wait around 7 months of something, iTunes Connect removes your app and the same name can't be used again.

Is there a way to... remove that time limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 4 months and no, there is no way to extend it, although I have heard unconfirmed reports of people talking to Apple and getting it extended, but I would not count on that.

I asked this very question on the Apple forums and was told by several people to just create a dummy App, do all your testing and then when you know you can complete it in less than 4 months, create a new final app.  The downside is you have to reenter all your leader board and achievement information.